# Why does Nuxt's proxy wont work in production mode with my setup

Tags: javascript, proxy, fetch, nuxt.js, basic-authentication

To avoid users know what endpoint we are requesting data, we are using [@nuxtjs/proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/proxy)

This config in **nuxt.config.js**

```
const deployTarget = process.env.NUXTJS_DEPLOY_TARGET || 'server'
const deploySSR = (process.env.NUXTJS_SSR === 'true') || (process.env.NUXTJS_SSR === true)
```

And the proxy settings

```
proxy: {
  '/api/**/**': {
    changeOrigin: true,
    target: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
    secure: true,
    ws: false,
    pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' }
  }
},
```

Also we deploy like so

```
NUXTJS_DEPLOY_TARGET=server NUXTJS_SSR=false nuxt build && NUXTJS_DEPLOY_TARGET=server NUXTJS_SSR=false nuxt start
```

Also in the httpClient that normally is

```
constructor (basePath, defaultTimeout, fetch, AbortController) {
  this.basePath = basePath
  this.defaultTimeout = parseInt(defaultTimeout, 10) || 1000
  this.isLocalhost = !this.basePath || this.basePath.includes('localhost')
  this.fetch = fetch
  this.AbortController = AbortController
}
```

Has been modified like so:

```
constructor (basePath, defaultTimeout, fetch, AbortController) {
  this.basePath = '/api'
  this.defaultTimeout = parseInt(defaultTimeout, 10) || 1000
  this.isLocalhost = !this.basePath || this.basePath.includes('localhost')
  this.fetch = fetch
  this.AbortController = AbortController
}
```

The fetch options are

```
_getOpts (method, options) {
  const opts = Object.assign({}, options)
  opts.method = opts.method || method
  opts.cache = opts.cache || 'no-cache'
  opts.redirect = opts.redirect || 'follow'
  opts.referrerPolicy = opts.referrerPolicy || 'no-referrer'
  opts.credentials = opts.credentials || 'same-origin'
  opts.headers = opts.headers || {}
  opts.headers['Content-Type'] = opts.headers['Content-Type'] || 'application/json'
  if (typeof (opts.timeout) === 'undefined') {
    opts.timeout = this.defaultTimeout
  }

  return opts
}
```

So that's making a request to https://api.anothersite.com/api/?request..

And in localhost using `npm run dev` its working just fine, it requests and fetchs the desired data.

But some how, when we deploy it to the staging environment all those request return

```
{ "code": 401, "data": "{'statusCode':401,'error':'Unauthorized','message':'Invalid token.'}", "json": { "statusCode": 401, "error": "Unauthorized", "message": "Invalid token." }, "_isJSON": true }
```

Note that

- the front is being deployed to  example.com that requires basic http authentication and we are properly authenticated
- The requests in both in local and staging are done to api.example.com that doesn't require http auth where the data is served from a Strapi that doesn't need any token at all

is it posible that this response that we are getting is because as requests are from the proxy they are not http authenticated?

Comment: You're using SSR or SSG?

Comment: @kissu The SSR is false, I think is a dynamic mode? this it what it's run `NUXTJS_DEPLOY_TARGET=server NUXTJS_SSR=false nuxt build && NUXTJS_DEPLOY_TARGET=server NUXTJS_SSR=false nuxt start`

Comment: Not sure why you do use env variables when launching your app. Stick to the env in `nuxt.config.js` IMO. What do you need, an SPA, SSG or SSR app? I'm not sure that the proxy is different in anything else than SSR tbh. So that would be `ssr: true` + `target: 'server'`and the usage of `yarn build` +`yarn start` once in production. Where do you host your app?

Comment: because we don't want to expose those variable values to the repository. We deploy them via github actions. We need to those request to be launched on every page load because if not when any API change we would have to redeploy the frontend for it to notice. So SSG won't be an option. We are trying to use the proxy like i mentioned in the question to avoid exposing the API domain. I'm not sure i'm answering your questions

Comment: Also we are already only using the ENV VARS in the nuxt.confg.js

Comment: What's the relationship between exposing something and prefixing your build step? You can totally use env vars to set those `ssr` and `target` flags. I mean, it's more explicit and easier to understand for everybody with properly defined values in your Nuxt config file. Since you're using SSR, it's at least solving the requirement for the proxy. Where do you host your app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249034/discussion-between-toni-michel-caubet-and-kissu).

Comment: You should find somebody who knows some details because you will need those pretty soon. Especially because here, you're hosting your app somewhere and that platform is probably missing an env token (hence the error).

Comment: Simplest way to solve that one is still to make a small repro IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You should find somebody who knows some details because you will need those for that project.
Especially because here, you're hosting your app somewhere and that platform is probably missing an environment variable, hence the quite self-explanatory error

> 401,'error':'Unauthorized','message':'Invalid token

That also explains why that one works locally (you probably have an `.env` file) and not once pushed.

---

You could try to create a repro on an SSR-ready VPS but I'm pretty sure that [@nuxtjs/proxy](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module#readme) is working fine.
Otherwise, double checking the network requests in your browser devtools is still the way to go regarding the correct configuration of the module.
Anyway, further details are needed from your side here.

---

As a good practice, you should also have the following in your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
ssr: true,
target: 'server'
```

rather than using inline variables for those, safer and self-explanatory for everybody that way (on top of being less error-prone IMO). Or, you can use an env variable for the key itself.

Comment: we have all the env vars set in the server with the expected values

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet why do you have a 401 error so? Something is not authorized for sure. Check maybe the API calls in the network tab.

Comment: the only authentication needed is the basic auth, i fear the proxy requests doesn't validate it even that the user is

Comment: Why do you have a proxy in the first place? I guess the proxy works if your project is properly setup as SSR. Can't you double check the network requests?

Comment: We are using the proxy to avoid users know our real endpoint

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet not sure if it's worth shipping a whole SSR app for just this. Could use a regular server doing just that or even a serverless function, will remove some load from your Nuxt app's server.

Comment: oh that's for a different issue.. in static mode would not detect new posts until re-deployed

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet even more argument to remove some load from a server already doing some heavy lifting IMO. Still, the proxy should still work fine I guess. Where are you hosting it?

Comment: Do you think that you post answer the question? should not be a comment?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I still stand by the fact that you're missing an environment variable on the platform you're hosting your app on. I didn't try to host a nuxt proxy module on an SSR-ready VPS myself but a repro would be doable pretty quickly. Further debugging + few things could be fixed but the error is quite self-explanatory here. I could have posted a huge comment but I want to limit a bit the spam down there and potentially edit my answer with my whole ideas. On top of that, if nobody posts an answer, nobody will get the bounty and this would be lost for everybody, so here I am.

Comment: There's not any environment variable missing (like I mentioned the last 30th). Actually it only fails if we try to use the proxy, if not, it works just fine. there's not any environment variable that's it's specific for the proxy.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet what is the difference in terms of calls so? What is not working properly, can you inspect the given network requests? Make a proper repro? Are you sure about your settings here? What if you try to hardcode some of the given env values? Maybe a dev/production regarding some of the tokens?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is issue is 100% not involving env vars. If you have any other ideas I'll be happy to elaborate further. I hope you understand

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet already gave some leads into my previous comment.

Comment: in your previous comment you are still referencing env variables (suggesting to hardcode them)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet yes but only. And with what you give us here, I still need to double check everything that I can. With more debugging material/time/overall context, I would maybe have more ideas but this is all I have to propose as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is causes by case sensitive, nuxt/proxy forwarded the all the headers in lowercase so instead of getting Authorization header on your api use authorization.

Maybe you are using windows on your local environment which does not require case sensitive.

```
 array(12) { ["sec-fetch-site"]=> string(11) "same-origin" ["sec-fetch-mode"]=> string(4) "cors" ["sec-fetch-dest"]=> string(5) "empty" ["cookie"]=> string(18) "i18n_redirected=en" ["referer"]=> string(27) "http://localhost:3000/stats" ["connection"]=> string(5) "close" **["authorization"]**=> string(47) "Bearer e63a62b6e8ee6b3749dc5f01fae33d37a751aba2" ["accept-encoding"]=> string(17) "gzip, deflate, br" ["accept-language"]=> string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.5" ["accept"]=> string(33) "application/json, text/plain, */*" ["user-agent"]=> string(84) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0" ["host"]=> string(14) "localhost:8081" }
```